# mysqli_stmt_bind_param() data not supplied when a question mark is a part of the query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Similar questions have been asked many times, but after reading almost every of these for over 5 hours, i have not found a suitable reply for my problem.

Im not an experience php / mysql developer, but i ve managed similar situations with the use of mysqli_stmt_bind_param() func.

Here is the query:

```
$query = 'SELECT Recipes.* , Categories.* FROM `Recipes` JOIN `Categories` ON JSON_EXTRACT(Recipes.category, \'$.category\') = \'Category ?\' WHERE Categories.category = ?';
```

I use this php code:

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbManager->getDBInstance(), $query)){

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ii", $id, $id);

    }
```

Because i have a model on the client side like:

```
{
    "category" : "...",
    "recipes" : [{...},{...}]
}
```

The error is: ****Fatal error**:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement**

I have already made similar queries with many more parameters, without any error: however, this is the first time i use the JSON_EXTRACT func from mysql.

I believe the error is caused by the $. which is not escaped correctly. The parameters to be replaced reference to the same variable, $id, which is an integer, and gets used for string interpolation in the first case ('Category 1') and as number after the WHERE clause.

Consider that, by not using mysqli_stmt_bind_param, the same query on phpmyadmin returns what i want, but that would open my code to mysql injections, which i want to avoid.

Also, notice that if i pass just one parameter to the function, the script gets executed (with wrong results), like if the query gets truncated at some point... i properly escaped every single quote, and even tried with double quotes, but the error is always the same.
Any hint on how to prevent the injection and achieve the result would be highly appreciated, because i really can't figure it out by myself.
Thank you

Comment: This comment is not relevant to your query parameter issue, but FYI your query is bound to do a table-scan on `Recipes` because using a function in the join condition like you're doing cannot use an index. On the other hand, you might not notice because you're not likely to have millions of rows in a table called `Recipes`. :-)

Comment: @BillKarwin probably as you say, i could use an id for the recipe rows which leads to the correct category, i even thought about that, but i was too curious to accomplish this with the json extract: probably, having and id would speed the search, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Only if you put an index on that `Recipes.category_id` column. Your reason for using JSON is similar to many other developers' I've seen here on Stack Overflow — they're using JSON only for the sake of curiosity. Once you experience how inefficient it is to use JSON in a relational database, you'll use it only when absolutely necessary. And _never_ call `JSON_EXTRACT()` in a `JOIN` clause, or a `WHERE` clause, or any other clause besides the select-list.

Comment: @BillKarwin the reason is i have already a consistent datasource coming from a json. Many keys have been properly mapped, but 2 columns still present a long text data type, and that s because i dont have any experience with relational databases. Replies like your however, help and speed up learning for newbies like me, so, thank you very much for your point of view and tips.

Comment: You might like my presentation [How to Use JSON in MySQL Wrong](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-use-json-in-mysql-wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two parameters in the call to `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`, but there's only one placeholder in `$query`. The first `?` is inside quotes, so it's treated literally, not as a placeholder.

You can use `CONCAT()` to concatenate a string literal with a placeholder, so change it to:

```
$query = '
    SELECT Recipes.* , Categories.* 
    FROM `Recipes` 
    JOIN `Categories` ON JSON_EXTRACT(Recipes.category, \'$.category\') = CONCAT(\'Category \', ?) 
    WHERE Categories.category = ?';
```

Comment: I could never think about the use of concat, so much to learn still. Thanks @barmar, your reply helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

A placeholder can represent a **complete data literal only**. To put it simple - anything you would write in quotes (or a number). So it shouldn't be `'Category ?'` but just `?` where Category could be concatenated in PHP.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `Recipes` JOIN `Categories` ON 
          JSON_EXTRACT(Recipes.category, \'$.category\') = ?
          WHERE Categories.category = ?';
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbManager->getDBInstance(), $query);
$category = "Category $id";
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"si", $category, $id);
```